# Passing a variable to a request-promise function inside a forEach loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, foreach

I am calling an API for price data which is working correctly. However, I am trying to pass the variable `exchange_pair_id` into the `then()` function.

Inside the forEach loop the exchange_pair_id is correct for each `asset`. However inside the `then()` function this variable is always the same (the last value in the forEach loop).

I am trying to pass the `exchange_pair_id` variable into `then(function(response) {...}`

```
response.forEach(function(asset) {
    var assets = asset['assets'];
        exchange_pair_id = asset['exchange_pair_id'];

    options.uri = exchange_objects[exchange[0]].ticker + '?pair=' + assets[0] + assets[1]; // overwrite to fit the request to Kraken API

    console.log(exchange_pair_id) // unique

    rp(options).then(function(response) {
        key = Object.keys(response['result']);
        price_data = response['result'][key];

        console.log(exchange_pair_id) // duplicate
    });                 
});
```

Comment: this should work if you use "let exchange_pair_id = asset['exchange_pair_id'];". just try it, because you define exchange_pair_id every time in the context of your callback function

Comment: What @MarouenMhiri want so say is that you have to make sure to scope your variables properly. Each variable without the keyword `var`, `let` or `const` are global variables. You want them scoped in your forEach, so it's important to write `var exchange_pair_id;`.

Comment: Thanks both, very amateur mistake that had me rattled for hours this morning. My fault for not understanding proper declaration of variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens due to the fact, that the function in the `.then()` is executed after the request-promise resolves, which takes some time. In the meanwhile the `forEach`-loop finishes and assigns the last `asset` to `exchange_pair_id` - which in your code is a global variable as a proper declaration is missing (see below)! After that the first request-promises begin to resolve and execute their callback, but at this time the `forEach`-loop is already finished so `exchange_pair_id` will always log the same value.

To avoid that `exchange_pair_id` is in the global scope, you should use a `,` instead of `;` after `var assets = asset['assets'];` (second line). Or simply add another var in front of `exchange_pair_id = asset['exchange_pair_id'];`

```
response.forEach(function(asset) {
    var assets = asset['assets'], // <---- use ',' instead of ';'
        exchange_pair_id = asset['exchange_pair_id'];

    options.uri = exchange_objects[exchange[0]].ticker + '?pair=' + assets[0] + assets[1]; // overwrite to fit the request to Kraken API

    console.log(exchange_pair_id) // unique

    rp(options).then(function(response) {
        key = Object.keys(response['result']);
        price_data = response['result'][key];

        console.log(exchange_pair_id) // duplicate
    });                 
});
```

> 1. Declared variables are constrained in the execution context in which they are declared. Undeclared variables are always global.

(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var)

Anyway I recommend you to use `let` in order to declare variables as it may sometimes prevent undesirable behaviour of your code. See the MDN docs on `let` to get to know what it does - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let

Answer (score 0):

Here you are experiencing an asynchronous problem.

When you execute the forEach you push tasks into the node.js to do list.

[image]

Then when you function stop, they get executed and access id.

[image]