# How to POST or save two different objects in one function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongoose, schema

I have a mongoose function that I am trying to use to create an object in my User object and another within my Listing object. I've tried saving twice, but am getting an error and only saving the first. How else can I do this?

Schemas below.

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
  created: { type: Date },
  email: { type: String, unique: true, lowercase: true },
  password: { type: String, select: false },
  listings: [Listing.schema],
  myBids: [Bids.schema]
});

var ListingSchema = new Schema({
  topic: String,
  uid: String,
  bids: [Bid.schema]
})

var BidSchema = new Schema({
  uid: String,
  respondEmail: String,
  response: String,
});
```

My create function. Creating a Bid object within the Listing. I now want to create a duplicate Bid object within the current User.

```
function create(req, res) {
  db.Listing.findById(req.params.listingId, function(err, foundListing) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('Error:', err);
    }
    db.User.findOne({
      'listings._id': req.params.listingId
    }, function(err, foundUser) {
      for (let i = 0; i < foundUser.listings.length; i++) {
        if (foundUser.listings[i]._id == req.params.listingId) {
          db.User.findById(req.user, function(err, currentUser) {

            var newBid = new db.Bid(req.body);

            // trying to push here
            // currentUser.myBid.push(newBid);
            // currentUser.save();
            var oldLength = foundUser.listings[i].bids.length;

            foundUser.listings[i].bids.set(oldLength, newBid);
            foundUser.save(function(err, savedListing) {
              if (err) {
                console.log('Error: ', err);
                return;
              }
              res.json(newBid);
            });
          })
        }
      }
    })
  });
};
```

Comment: Look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46321446/passing-a-variable-to-a-request-promise-function-inside-a-foreach-loop/46321693#46321693)

Comment: Thanks - By setting a Timeout of 1 millisecond, it is now working.